# rollbar django suddenly not working. AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'

Tags: python, django, openssl, rollbar

My rollbar suddenly does not work on my django python app. It was working previously until i merge something. it looks more like openssl issue?

```
>>> import rollbar
>>> rollbar.init('xxxxxx', 'production') 
>>> rollbar.report_message('Got an IOError in the main loop', 'warning')
'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'
>>> From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x7f08351e8730>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deploy/railerdotcom/railerdotcomenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 313, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: module 'lib' has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
```

I am using:

```
Django==1.11.7
Ubuntu version 16.04
```

Comment: Check your cryptography version.  pyOpenssl apparently requires cryptography 2.1.4 or greater: https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/728

Comment: definitely right. i just updated to 2.2.2 and it works

Comment: Good to know. :)  I'll pop this into an answer so people know it's resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because pyOpenssl requires cryptography 2.1.4 or greater:

https://github.com/pyca/pyopenssl/issues/728